# In Python and GAE: How to permanently cache data from a Datastore across HTTP GET requests

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an online product using GAE and Python. Certain data in my Model (i.e. Datastore) are constant across `Context`s: which means for all incoming HTTP `GET` requests, those data don't change.

For the sake of argument, assume that said data must live in the Datastore as opposed to static pages (e.g html).

How would I set the Google App Engine Caching policies so that the Datastore is only queried once in the life of the application -- even if the product is experiencing millions of hits per day?

DISCLAIMER: I am a complete newbie to both Python and GAE.

I am presently looking into global variables, which I would use to store said query results. Not only do I not yet know how that would work, there is another problem: Different HTTP `GET` requests (i.e. urls) are for different portions and views of said constant data.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it. I was reading https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache. But was not sure about it.

Comment: If you use the NDB API (the new datastore) it will take care of caching.

Comment: If the data never changes, why store it in the datastore or memcache in the first place? Make it a data file for your app to read in.

Comment: @RocketDonkey, will you please re-post your comment as a response so I may accept? Otherwise this post will linger as open indefinitely.

Comment: @kasavbere Sure thing, just posted. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [Memcache API](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache). It will allow you to do basically what you want - cache the results of a query (or even the resulting page as HTML) and serve it while it is available (you can set an expiry, but you will also occasionally experience cache misses where the datastore is queried anyway). Also, as @voscausa mentions, switching your datastore API from `db` to `ndb` will provide automatic caching with additional options to further modify caching behavior (docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache)).